# Ruby .times method returns variable instead of output

Tags: ruby, methods, rspec, iteration

In order to pass an rspec test, I need to get a simple string to be returned "num" amount of times. I've been googling and it seems the .times method should help. In theory from what I can see:

```
num = 2
string = "hello"

num.times do
  string
end
```

...Should work? But the output continues to return as "2", or whatever "num" is equal to. I can get it to "puts 'hello'" twice, but it still returns "2" after printing "hellohello".

Also tried

```
num.times { string }
```

Am I missing something fundamental about the .times method, here? Or should I be going about this another way?

Comment: the `times` method repeatedly calls a block of code `num` times -
 it is not the "times" (multiplication) operator. For that use `*` e.g. `"hello" * 2 # => "hellohello"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[times](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Integer.html#method-i-times) will repeat the execution of the block: `string` will be interpreted twice, but the value won't be used for anything. `num.times` will return `num`. You can check it in a Ruby console :

```
> 2.times{ puts "hello" }
hello
hello
 => 2
```

You don't need a loop, you need concatenation:

```
string = "hello"
string + string
# "hellohello"
string + string + string
# "hellohellohello"
```

Or just like with numbers, you can use multiplication to avoid multiple additions :

```
string * 3
# "hellohellohello"
num = 2
string * num
# "hellohello"
```

If you need a list with 2 `string` elements, you can use :

```
[string] * num
# ["hello", "hello"]
```

or

```
Array.new(num) { string }
# ["hello", "hello"]
```

If you want to join the strings with a space in the middle :

```
Array.new(num, string).join(' ')
# "hello hello"
```

Just for fun, you could also use :

```
[string] * num * " "
```

but it's probably not really readable.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the behavior you're looking for?

```
def repeat(count, text)
  text * count
end

repeat(2, "hello") #  => "hellohello"
```

(No steps were taken to defend against bad input)

Comment: Essentially, yes. I think many answers here have shown that using a loop like .times might have been an overcomplication.